# Oracle STANDARD_HASH not available in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, hash, plsql

I'm trying to use STANDARD_HASH Oracle (12c) function in PL/SQL but seems not available:

```
SQL> exec   dbms_output.put_line(STANDARD_HASH('test'));
BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(STANDARD_HASH('test')); END;

                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 28:
PLS-00201: identifier 'STANDARD_HASH' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

From sql is working just fine:

```
SQL> select STANDARD_HASH('test') from dual;

STANDARD_HASH('TEST')
----------------------------------------
A94A8FE5CCB19BA61C4C0873D391E987982FBBD3
```

Why? What is the best way to implement the STANDARD_HASH in PLSQL?

Regards

Comment: Not all SQL functions are available in PL/SQL; it isn't [on this list](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00212) but perhaps should be. Might fall into the same category as LNNVL.

Comment: That is the more correct answer than usage of custom wrapper function which is re-invention of the wheel. Definitely this variant must be marked as a correct answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems like it isn't yet a part of PL/SQL in `12c`.

As a workaround, use `SELECT INTO` in **PL/SQL**:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    str VARCHAR2(40);
  3  BEGIN
  4    SELECT STANDARD_HASH('test') INTO str FROM dual;
  5    dbms_output.put_line(str);
  6  END;
  7  /
A94A8FE5CCB19BA61C4C0873D391E987982FBBD3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I would suggest to **create a function**, and use it whenever you need it in **PL/SQL**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION STANDARD_HASH_OUTPUT(str IN VARCHAR2)
  2    RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  AS
  4    op VARCHAR2(40);
  5  BEGIN
  6    SELECT STANDARD_HASH(str) INTO op FROM dual;
  7    RETURN op;
  8  END;
  9  /

Function created.
```

Call the **function** directly in **PL/SQL block**:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     dbms_output.put_line(STANDARD_HASH_OUTPUT('test'));
  3  END;
  4  /
A94A8FE5CCB19BA61C4C0873D391E987982FBBD3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit! Seems like I will implement this method as the dbms_crypto.hash function seems to be much slower (avg.43%). I prefer to avoid select from dual (personal opinion) but in this case I will go with this solution.

Comment: In 19c still the same

Answer (score 3):

For text, *STANDARD_HASH* is the same as *DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH* with SHA1:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_crypto.hash(cast('test' as clob), dbms_crypto.hash_sh1));
end;
/
```

Output:

```
A94A8FE5CCB19BA61C4C0873D391E987982FBBD3
```

For other data types, it's not documented how they are passed to the hash function.

Comment: Thanks Codo! For some reason  this method is slower (because of the cast to clob?) than a select from dual using the STANDARD_HASH function. I'm surprised!

Comment: That's interesting indeed. I would have expected the SELECT to be slower as it involves a context switch. But it's always better to measure than to assume. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score -2):

standard hash allows you to specify hash algorithm.  Algorithms are SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, and MD5. If you omit this argument, then SHA1 is used.

To get a more familiar GUID than sys_guid provides:

```
LOWER (CAST (standard_hash (SYS_GUID (), 'MD5') AS VARCHAR2 (40)))
```

I've tested on 20.5 million records with no collisions...

Comment: Another benefit is that this method uses all built-in functions and can be used for a column DEFAULT.  Since you can't use user defined functions, procedures and packages in DEFAULT values I was looking for a way to stick with buit-in functions to morph the SYS_GUID into a more visually distinguishable format .